# query specific exchange 2013 folder EWS

Tags: c#, find, exchangewebservices

Any help, links, or thoughts are greatly appreciate. Thanks!

**Overall target**

How do i query a specific fold in exchange 2013 to read the body of each message so that i can gather information from automated alerts and write to a csv file?

**specific question i cannot figure out**

how do i query a specific folder?

**problem**

i can only find examples of how to search the inbox. I need to change that statement to say a specific folder.

**current code section where issue lies**

```
 try
            {
                //read the subject line of the 10 most recently recieved emails in the inbox
                FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
                foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**line of issue**

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    //create searchable object called rootfolder and set root to equal Inbox
    Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    //foreach child folder inside Ibox
    foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
    {
        //if the child folder is named hey
        if (folder.DisplayName.Contains("hey"))
        {
            //create searchable object of child of root but now is root to be searched within folder and set it as root folder
            Folder childfolder = Folder.Bind(service, folder.Id);
            //foreach childfolder to new root
            foreach (Folder cfolder in childfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
            {
                //if child folder is blah then search items
                if (cfolder.DisplayName.Contains("blah"))
                {
                    //create searchable object of blah folder and set it as root folder
                    FindItemsResults<Item> blah = service.FindItems(cfolder.Id, new ItemView(10));
                    //this will load all the extra properites for each email (SUCH AS BODY)
                    service.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in blah select item, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                    foreach (Item item in blah.Items)
                    {
                       //Console.WriteLine(item.DateTimeReceived + "\n\t" + item.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine("\t"+item.DateTimeReceived);
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + item.Body.Text.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity, here is code to locate a folder by a specific name (assuming only one folder with this name exists) in EWS 2010:

```
Public Function GetMailFolderByName(ByVal folderName As String) As Folder Implements IMailboxExchange.GetMailFolderByName
    Me.ThrowIfNoConnection()
    Dim folderView As FolderView = New FolderView(1)
    folderView.PropertySet = New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)
    folderView.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName)
    folderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep
    Dim searchFilterByFolderName As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(FolderSchema.DisplayName, folderName)
    Dim results As FindFoldersResults = Me._exchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, searchFilterByFolderName, folderView)
    If results Is Nothing OrElse results.Folders Is Nothing OrElse results.Folders.Count = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Return results.Folders(0)
End Function
```

**Important:**
Yes, I know it is in VB.NET, but should be translatable to C#.  It is also EWS 2010 and not 2013, but they might not have changed that much.